# Nape bodyList ignores bodies

Tags: actionscript-3, nape

I have 13 bodies on the nape space (5 static and 8 dynamic),
when i loop through bodylist to remove dynamic bodies, the loop reads only 9 bodies(5 static and 4 dynamic)and ignores the 4 other dynamic
however the bodylist length gives me 13 when tracing it
anyone has any idea what is the problem might be?
I create the body with click

```
var body:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
```

and when removing

```
var bList:BodyList = space.bodies;
for(var i:int = 0; i< bList.length; i++)
{
   var bod:Body = bList.at(i);
   if(bod.type == BodyType.DYNAMIC)
   {
       bod.space = null;
   }

}
```

Comment: it's a strange behaviour, could you give us more info? Maybe a snippet?

Comment: i've added code sample